# recursive loop using apply R

Tags: r, for-loop, recursion, apply

I have got two loops I want to transform using some apply function in order to reduce the computation time. First one seems easy to do, the problem arises with the second one because the S is updated with its own value in each iteration.

```
S0   = 100
a    = 0.00016
b    = 0.0126
sim    = 10000 
drifts = 1000
Si = rep(0,sim)

for(i in (1:sim))
{
 S =  S0
 for (j in (1:drifts))
  {
   z = rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = 1)
   S = S * exp(a + b*z)
  }
  Si[i] =S 
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: The computations done in the `j` loop are not being stored or used anywhere. So why a loop `j` is used? Looks like you missed something.

Comment: It seems j loop udpates S value in every iteration, while i- loop resets value to S0

Comment: @Antonis that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like the code below. I have replaced the j-loop with a product, I think the math is correct.

```
sapply(1:sim,function(x) S0*prod(exp(a + b*rnorm(drifts))))
```

it is also significantly faster:

```
> system.time(for(i in (1:sim))
+ {
+   S =  S0
+   for (j in (1:drifts))
+   {
+     z = rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = 1)
+     S = S * exp(a + b*z)
+   }
+   Si[i] =S 
+ }
+ )
   user  system elapsed 
  23.29    0.02   23.34 
> 
> system.time(Si<-sapply(1:sim,function(x) S0*prod(exp(a + b*rnorm(drifts)))))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.76    0.00    1.76
```

Comment: This is definitely the best way to do it, nice

Answer (score 1):

```
calc_s <- function(S, i = 1) {
  S <- S * exp(a + b * rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = 1))
  return (if (i < drifts) calc_s(S, i + 1) else S)}
S2 <- sapply(1:sim, function(x) {
  calc_s(S0)
})
```

It isn't faster though